# SignalR calling clients from outside the hub does not work

Tags: asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub

I am evaluating SignalR with a very simple example to be able to call the clients from the server. I have installed the latest version of SignalR using Nuget in an empty Visual Studio web application - Visual Studio 2012. The scenario is: I have an aspx Publisher that pushes messages from the code behind i.e by clicking the publish button. There is a html client that should receive the message. The code is below however not sure why the message is not passed to client. I have no error messages. SignalR Owin startup is called ok. If I type /Signalr/hubs url, I get the SignalR message.

The code is:
Hub:

```
namespace SignalRTest2
{
    public class TestHub : Hub
    {

        // not needed??
    }
}
```

Publisher:

```
public partial class Publisher : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void cmdBroadcast_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var testHub = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<TestHub>();
        testHub.Clients.All.clientSendMessage(txtMessage.Text);
    }
}
```

Client:

```
<head>

<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.0.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>

<title></title>

<script type="text/javascript">

    //Proxy created on the fly
    var myHub = $.connection.testHub;

    // Declare a function on the chat hub so the server can invoke it
    myHub.clientSendMessage = function (message) {
        //$("#messages").append("<li>" + message + "</li>");
        alert(message);
    };

    $.connection.hub.start()

</script>
```

Comment: Checkout the docs. myHub.client.clientSendMessage is what you want,

Comment: thanks that was it. ;) Somehow I can't mark it as a answer though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout the [docs](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/introduction-to-signalr). myHub.client.clientSendMessage is what you want.